# Gradle Problem, After My Build to android, [ Ionic ]

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\User\Downloads\ionicfix\ioniclastest\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\User\Downloads\ionicfix\ioniclastest\platforms\android\build.gradle
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

```
    cordova.cmd build android exited with exit code 1.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem..
I changed the gradle to 7.0.3 (maybe it works with 7.1.1) and also the gradle JDK in Android Studio (Preferences... -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle) to version 11.
Sometimes you have to reload Android Studio from VSCode to get it work.

Comment: This problem solve from myself, i change a jdk version to 8, after that i'm change sdk android studio, version to 30.0.0. Thank you for your helping